# SikulixIDE How do I change to utf-8

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I am using SikulixIDE in python, but a can't change the encoding to utf-8. Someone help-me?

```
Settings.MoveMouseDelay=0.0
click("1465260706046.png")
sleep(2)
type("ação")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue. The bug is documented [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1299462).

The source of this issue is the Java AWT Robot that is used for Sikuli's `type()`. The usage of the `type()` is generally restricted to whatever you can produce with your keyboard (which in fact includes some on-ascii characters on many non-EN keyboards). The current version of Sikuli up to 1.0.1 is restricted, to a subset of what Java finally "presses" on your keyboard, taking the given character as the one from the US-layout.

Some restrictions can be overcome, if you know, which US-EN-key to press, to produce a wanted character with your local keyboard layout.

On Windows, there is a trick with the num keys and the <kbd>alt</kbd> key to produce non-ascii characters. Press and hold <kbd>alt</kbd> and press the 3-digit decimal representation of the character 
code on the num pad.

If this is a solution for you: you can do that with type, you only need a translation function.

The actual Sikuli code is on github (https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014). The key translation is done in the class `Key`. The interface to Java AWT Robot is in class `DesktopRobot`.

[Source](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/246217)